# How to optimize WP_Query (includes CPT and ACF)

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed

I've been building my site and was testing the performance today with WP-plugin QueryMonitor. Pageload on one specific page is 30s! On that page I want to print out lists from two custom post types - I have two queries. One custom post type has over 3000 posts to go through, other one has maybe 400 to go through. All the posts have also ACF-fields and I'm mainly printing those ACF-fields on the page.

QueryMonitor is giving me:
Page Generation Time
29,4764
98,3% of 30s limit

Peak Memory Usage
14 392 kB
11,0% of 131 072 kB limit

Database Query Time
29,3400

Database Queries
Total: 37

Cache is not turned on yet, but the pages are usually visited only once etc, so caching might not be the answer.

I need pagination, so no_found_rows is not the answer. For the other query that is already set and it sped up the page a little.

My problematic query looks like this:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
    'post_type'      => 'horse',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'owner_id_num',
            'value'   => $userid,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'show_horse_profile',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    )
);
// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I'm just wondering that how can I speed up my query. It takes sooooo much time right now.

// Edit. Tried custom query, getting error "[Unknown column 'wp_posts.ID' in 'on clause']". Can't work through it...

```
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta, $wpdb->postmeta AS mt1
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 

AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'owner_id_num'   
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = $userid
AND mt1.meta_key = 'show_horse_profile'
AND mt1.meta_value = '1'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'horse'

ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
```

And I'm trying to print:

```
$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table" );
$items_per_page = $posts_per_page;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$latestposts = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );
?>
<table class="table horse-list-profile">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Hevonen</th>
        <th>Painotus</th>
        <th>Talli</th>
        <th>Ensiarvostelutulos</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

<?php
foreach ($latestposts as $currentPost) {
    $breed_ID = get_field("breed");
    $breed = get_field("short", $breed_ID);
    $disc = get_field_object("discipline");
    $disc_value = $disc['value'];
    $disc_label = $disc['choices'][ $disc_value ];
    $skp = get_field_object('sex');
    $skp_value = $skp['value'];
    if ($skp_value == '0') { $sex = 't'; }
    else if ($skp_value == '1') { $sex = 'o'; }
    else if ($skp_value == '2') { $sex = 'r'; }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $breed; ?>-<?php echo $sex; ?> <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $disc_label; ?></td>
        <td><?php if(get_field("stable_id", get_the_ID())) { echo get_the_title(get_field("stable_id", get_the_ID())); } else { echo '-'; } ?></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo get_field("basic_evaluation_grade"); ?></strong> <small><?php echo get_field("basic_evaluation_points"); ?>/1900p.</small></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Total 37 queries are running on the page. Which is the most time-consuming query from it? If you think that the above query is only causing this issue then comment that query and check the Page load time again.

Comment: You may also replace the current query with the custom query so that may reduce the time as well. I have applied this on multiple sites. Also, try to get the ACF fields in the custom queries.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui the most time consuming query is the one I posted, it takes 27s. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by custom query - something like this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query?

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Comment: Please let me know either you are still working on the optimization or done with it. I love to workaround on the optimization and security things.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @SamiAhmedSiddiqui:

Code includes a custom query with a custom pagination menu:

**Thats how I made it for my site but maybe you can find some use for it!**

```
$posts_per_page = 10;
switch (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ppp')) {  
        case '10':
            $posts_per_page10 = "selected=true";
            $posts_per_page = 10;
            break;
        case '25':
            $posts_per_page25 = "selected=true";
            $posts_per_page = 25;
            break;
        case '50':
            $posts_per_page50 = "selected=true";
            $posts_per_page = 50;
            break;
}


global $wpdb;

$query = 

("SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS postmeta1
            ON (postmeta1.post_id = $wpdb->posts.id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS postmeta2
            ON (postmeta2.post_id = $wpdb->posts.id)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'horse'
    AND (postmeta1.meta_key = „owner_id_num“
        AND postmeta1.meta_value = $user_id
    )
    AND (postmeta2.meta_key = „show_horse_profile“
        AND postmeta2.meta_value = 1
    )")
;

$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table" );
$items_per_page = $posts_per_page;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$latestposts = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );

foreach ($latestposts as $currentPost) {
 //get post content
}

$pag = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',

    'show_all'           => false,
    'end_size'           => 0,
    'mid_size'           => 2,
    'prev_next'          => true,
    'prev_text'          => __('< Pref'),
    'next_text'          => __('Next >'),
    'type'               => 'array',
    'add_args'           => false,
    'add_fragment'       => '',
    'before_page_number' => '',
    'after_page_number'  => '',
    'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
    'current' => $page
));



if(is_array($pag)){
    $last = end($pag);
    $first = reset($pag);
}


$prev = "";
$next = "";


if (\strpos($last, 'Next >') !== false) {
    $next = $last;
}
if(\strpos($first, '< Pref') !== false){
    $prev = $first;
}



<div class="paginationMenu">
    <div class="paginationPre">
        <?php echo $prev;?>
    </div>
    <div class="paginationPostsPerPage">
        Pagination:<select name="ppp" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option <?php echo $posts_per_page10?> value="10">10</option>
            <option <?php echo $posts_per_page25?> value="25">25</option>
            <option <?php echo $posts_per_page50?> value="50">50</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="paginationNext">
        <?php echo $next?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I changed the query based on this src:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40322/query-multiple-meta-key-values

```
$query = "  
        SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta, $wpdb->postmeta AS mt1
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 

        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'key1'   
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'value1'
        AND mt1.meta_key = 'key1'
        AND mt1.meta_value = 'value2'

        AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'horse'
        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
        ";
```

Comment: Thank you! Getting error "[Unknown column 'wp_posts.ID' in 'on clause']" though :/ attached the new query I tried on the first post.

Comment: @Heidi I added a change => Edit: ....
Maybe you are able to fix the error. 
I only tried the code with a single meta_key & meta_value and based on the link I have posted, I have tried to change it up for multiple values. Hope this might help you out.

Comment: @Heidi Please recheck as Kalti edited the query. Does it work for you or not? If the query is working for you then please check the query time and the result should the same as the default WordPress query. If both are fine then only move forward with the other changes instead of the one go.

Comment: Thank you both. Tried the new version. Now I'm not getting errors but looks like the query gets in some infinite loop, the page loads and loads and never finishes. I'll add my current query to my first post now.